# How to solve issue cannot implicitly convert System.Data.Datatable to int?

Tags: c#

I want to select the patient_no from sql server database and assign it to int variable by using stored procedure , then compare this value before insert into the database , my issue when i assign the value to variable by using stored procedure the following error appeared cannot implicitly convert type System.Data.Datatable to int.

I am using windows forms application not webform.

I tried to solve this error but i cannot .

1- the stored procedure to read patient_no :

```
create proc [VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST]
@Patient_No int
as 
select Patient_No from Users_web
where patient_no = @Patient_No
```

2- The public void used to get data from database :

```
public DataTable VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST(int Patient_No)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlParameter[] Param = new SqlParameter[1];
            Param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Patient_No", SqlDbType.Int);
            Param[0].Value = Patient_No;
            dt = DAL.SelectData("VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST", Param);
            DAL.close();
            return dt;
        }
```

3- The DataAccessLayer class which is used to read data from database:

```
public DataTable SelectData(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

            if (param != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
                {
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
                }
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
```

4- i called the class and stored procedure and try to assign returned value from stored procedure to int value :

```
BL.CLS_PATIENTS patient = new BL.CLS_PATIENTS();
int patient_exist = patient.VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST(Convert.ToInt32(txtPatientNo.Text));
```

the error appeared in step 4 , how to solve this error and what i need to change in my code.

I need to assign patient_no to int variable then i need to compare it and validate it if patient exist then show message this patient already exist if patient not exist then i will insert it to the database tables.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: `VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST`returns a `DataTable` and you're trying to convert it to an `int`. You have to select the row and column from which you want to extract that data using `dt.AsEnumerable().First().Field<int>("ColumnName")` for instance.

Comment: the error appeared in this line int patient_exist = patient.VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST(Convert.ToInt32(txtPatientNo.Text)); cannot convert implicitly convert type System.Data.DataTable to int , how to solve this error and assign the returned value to the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is returning a `DataTable` not an `int`.

You need to access the data in the `DataTable`.  This can be done in many ways:

```
BL.CLS_PATIENTS patient = new BL.CLS_PATIENTS();
var patientData = patient.VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST(Convert.ToInt32(txtPatientNo.Text));  // datatable

DataRow row = patientData.Rows[0];
int patientExists = row.Field<int>("Patient_No");
```

Or another option is:

```
int patientExists = int.Parse(patientData.Rows[0]["Patient_No"]);
```

A better option would be to update the VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXISTS method and refactor slightly:

```
    public int? GetPatientNumber(int Patient_No)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter[] Param = new SqlParameter[1];
        Param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Patient_No", SqlDbType.Int);
        Param[0].Value = Patient_No;
        dt = DAL.SelectData("VALIDATE_PATIENT_EXIST", Param);
        DAL.close();

        // if there is at least one row
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
            int? patientNumber = row.Field<int>("Patient_No");
            return patientNumber;
        }

        // return null otherwise
        return null;
    }
```

Then if you need to validate whether the patient exists you could do:

```
var patientNumber = GetPatientNumber(txtPatientNo.Text); // int?
bool patientExists = patientNumber.HasValue;
```

Comment: error appeared in this line                                                                                    
 int? patientNumber = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("Patient_No");                    'DataTable' Does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field<int>(DataRow,int,DataRowVersion) requires a receiver of type 'DataRow'

Comment: Have you added `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;` to the top of your file? That's neede for `.Field`.  I've just updated code slightly - you can define a `DataRow` variable.

Comment: Thank you for help really appreciate i will try your solution

Comment: @Abdullah Excellent, I'm glad you resolved it.  Please accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: I accepted the solution but another error appeared when try to insert to database error appeared in this line DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];      An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is no row at position 0.

Comment: I've updated my code (in the `GetPatientNumber` method). You need to check that a row exists (`Rows.Count > 0`)

Comment: its working now 100% and inserting data to database thank you so much , next time i will do the best to take positive points not -2 . I dont know what mistakes i did?